# Use rsync without copying files that are in use

Tags: backup, rsync

I have a server (Machine A) that receives uploads throughout the day from other machines.  I have a script running on another internal server (running as cron - Machine B) that uses rsync to pull these files onto itself and remove the originals on Machine A.  Some of these uploads last an hour or more.

How do I use rsync so that it won't attempt to copy files that are currently uploaded (being written to)?  I don't want it to pull partial uploads and then attempt to process them.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit on both machine A & B.

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

In order to make incremental baclups in `rsync`, you should put the `--update` or `-u` option. The only situation in which the a file existing in the receiver will be updated is when the archive exists and has the same timestamp in both ends but the size differs.

About the partial updates, all the temporary uploads are stored in a temporary archive and then moved to the `dest` directory when uploaded. you can use the `--partial` in case of a  `rsync` or network problem, this will resume the partial updates next time you execute the sync again.

You can check the whole options [from this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).